# Gradle - Can I manage task dependencies using convention properties?

Tags: groovy, gradle

I'm using Gradle as a build system for my project. 
What I want is to make task A depend on task B if a given property is set to "true". Is this doable, and if the answer is yes, how can I do that?

Currently, I'm using conventionMapping but this doesn't seem to work. My code looks like this:

```
MyTask.conventionMapping.propertyName = { MyPluginConvention.propertyName }

if (MyTask.propertyName.equals("true")) {
    MyTask.dependsOn ...
}
```

Thanks in advance,
Marin

Comment: Some more information would help. Is this code from a build script or a plugin class? Are MyTask and MyPluginConvention class names or variable names? Who declares task A, and who declares task B? Etc.

Comment: This code is from a plugin class. MyTask and MyPluginConvention are class names. MyTask extends DefaultTask and implements VerificationTask. Both these classes are declared by me. The task I want to depend on is also declared by me and it also extends DefaultTask and implements VerificationTask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of working with task/convention classes, you'll have to work with their *instances*. Also, you'll have to defer the decision whether to add a task dependency. For example:

```
def myTask = project.tasks.create("myTask", MyTask)
def otherTask = ...
def myConvention = new MyConvention()    
...
myTask.conventionMapping.propertyName = { myConvention.propertyName }
// defer decision whether to depend on 'otherTask'
myTask.dependsOn { myTask.propertyName == "true" ? otherTask : [] }
```

If there's no task variable in scope, you can also reference existing tasks via `project.myTask` or `project.tasks["myTask"]`.

PS: Convention objects have been largely replaced by [extension objects](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#N1561E).

Comment: Well.. this is exactly what I'm doing. This approach does not work because at this point of the plugin configuration, the property is not set yet. Gradle evaluates convention properties lazily. I have to find a way to 'force' the evaluation. How can I do that?

Comment: You said "MyTask and MyPluginConvention are class names". Hence 'MyTask.conventionMapping' etc. is wrong. That is, unless you use camel case for variable names, which is highly discouraged and, in the case of Groovy, can even break your code. I've updated my answer to cover the other problem.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. My first post was a bit messy. myTask and myPluginConvention are instances of user defined classes. Anyway... I figured out that I can use project.afterEvaluate method and it is all working now. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The deferred `dependsOn` in my answer serves the same purpose, and it's always good to avoid `afterEvaluate`. Thanks for accepting my answer.